# Misheard and Obscured

Tags: wordplay

My friend was trying to tell me an idiom he heard, but I think it got lost in translation. What he ended up telling me was this:

> Bread makeup
>   Not harmful
>   Obviously
>   525600s

Can you guys figure out what idiom he was trying to tell me?

**Note:**

As it has caused some confusion, everything written is correct.
Also to be clear I simply transcribed exactly what he said to me

**Hint:**

> s != seconds, s == s

**Hint 2:**

> You can't apply this makeup

Comment: Can you confirm that "525600s" is really correct? (If you look at the comments to the answers here you will see some reasons to suspect it *might* not be.)

Comment: Is this a popular English idiom, or a poorly-translated non-English idiom?

Comment: @rybo111 google will autofill the answer, does that answer your question?

Comment: it's an idiom, not a proverb, right?

Comment: @Sid 99%+ sure it is an idiom, so yes

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's what I got:

> Wet behind the ears

Each line is

> A word that has been misheard as a different word and then obscured by a synonym

Bread makeup

> Some bread is made of whey, kind of sounds like wet
>  **OP's** intended word for this clue: wheat

Not harmful

> Benign, sounds like behind

Obviously

> Duh, sounds like the (thanks Dan Russell)

525600s

> A year's worth of minutes, and year + s sounds like ears

Comment: This is correct! Though I had a different intended clue for the first line, yours fits perfectly well. Good job!

Comment: After I put in my answer, I thought of  your idea for the bread clue and was like "oops, of course", but I was swimming at the time...

Comment: As a total Renthead, I must now show myself the door for NOT recognizing that particular number.

Answer (score 5):

The best I can do is:

> **Rolling back the years**

Bread

> **Roll**

makeup

> **ink**

Not harmful

> = **back**, somehow?

Obviously

> "**duh**"

525600s

> 525600 minutes = **year**, then "s" = **s**

So

> Roll ink back duh year s → "**Rolling back the years**"

Comment: You have got some of the clues correct, but not the answer as a whole. Also a single line represents one word. Also don't miss the clue to solving the puzzle in the title

Comment: Actually after rereading your answer it looks like you heeded the title's clue, you are getting pretty warm

Answer (score 2):

Is it

> Better safe than sorry

Bread makeup

> You apply butter on bread so that is like bread makeup (butter = better)

not harmful

> safe

Obviously

525600s

> Still thinking about these two. 525600s should become "years", even though that doesn't fit in my answer.

Comment: 525600 *minutes* is a year.

Comment: Good guess, but not the answer I am looking for

Answer (score 1):

> The spirit is pure but the body is weak

Bread makeup

> Yeast produces alcohol, or spirits, to raise bread; in Christian theology the bread of Eucharist is also the holy spirit

Not harmful

> Unadulterated food is pure and not harmful

Obviously

> The body (of text) is literally obvious

525600s

> 525600 is the number of minutes in the year.  In seconds, 1/60 of a year is just shy of a week

Comment: Good attempt, but it is a bit of a stretch

Answer (score 1):

Off, most probably.

Is it:

> Icing on the cake? 
>  Bread makeup, literally. 
>  It really isn't harmful, is it? 
>  Obviously, icing ON the cake. 525,600... A year. Birthdays, anniversaries? Cakes!

Comment: Sorry, not the answer I am looking for. I also wouldn't consider bread to be the same as cake

Answer (score 0):

Maybe

> make up for lost time

Explanation

> Sometimes during the work the *brea*k, though not explicitly harmful, makes you hurry up to catch up once you begin working again. "for" and "time" taken from the last line: it looks like 52s, 56s, and 00s are *time*stamps with the interval of *four* seconds.

Comment: Sorry, not the answer I am looking for

Comment: @GordonAllocman Ok, it's still an attempt :) Am I anywhere close?

Comment: Not really. You are missing some of the clues, all of the clues are important

Comment: @Gordon Yes, haven't used some of them...

Answer (score 0):

Another attempt:

> make a killing

Bread

> one of the first needs when you start making money is food.

Not harmful

> Sounds dangerous, though it does mean *make money*, much money

Obviously

> probably paired with the next one, but could mean that there's nothing really difficult / unobvious when you have lots of money.

525600s

> s could be $, maybe it does mean much money for a short period.

Comment: But maybe you just mean something different by an *idiom*...

Comment: It is definitely an idiom

Answer (score 0):

I think,(This might be way off)

> Butter wouldn't melt in his mouth

Bread Makeup

> Butter(I think)

Not harmful
Obviously

> The idiom means someone who can do no harm.

525600s

> Not able to get this. Might be someone who can do no wrong even in a year.

Comment: Sorry not the answer I am looking for

Comment: Still an attempt, am I close?? Or Should I just give up?

Comment: Each line is separate, and you are missing a piece to the puzzle, but I wouldn't say you have to give up