# Misheard and Obscured: Jumbled Science edition

Tags: wordplay, science

(First iteration of this puzzle [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/35201/misheard-and-obscured), reading this puzzle is certainly not necessary but might help give an idea of what to do)

Hey guys, my friend just got back from one of his intro science classes (I don't know the exact subject) and he wanted to tell me a cool factoid he had heard. Unfortunately my friend managed to goof it up even worse this time. He couldn't remember the order of the words in the sentence in addition to his mistakes from last time! This is what he told me:

> Doofus
>   White donut, Garden rain bringer
>   Thorny smooch singer
>   Not west laterally
>   Golden touch, Picked by the ear, Post-shower hair care tool

I was able to determine there were also two instances of

> "the"

mixed in there as well.

Can you guys figure out what my friend was trying to tell me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A wild guess, probably premature, but everyone's favourite saying from school:

> Mitochondria is the powerhouse of the cell

'Golden touch'

> Could be none other than our King Midas, Midas = Mito

We have two instances of 'the'.

'Not west laterally'

> i.e. East = is

Not sure of the others, but I thought I'd just brainstorm this down.

**From Dan Russell**

Picked by the ear

> Corn --> 'chon'

Post-shower hair care tool

> Dryer --> 'dria'

White donut

> Powder --> Power

Garden rain bringer

> Hose --> House

Doofus

> Oaf -- Of

Thorny smooch singer

> Seal (Kiss from a rose) --> Cell

Comment: Some help: midas-corn-dryer, thorny singer=Seal, donut=powder garden rain=hose, doofus=oaf.

Comment: e_e Oh, just take it. **+1**

Comment: This is the correct answer! Good Job

Comment: @GordonAllocman And I thought I'd never use this phrase!